# Possible new type of plagiarism tool

Tags: research-process, authorship, plagiarism

I was wondering if there is a platform or a tool that can flag papers for being plagiarised? 
Brief: let's say I am researching on topic X and have used Y as a reference paper. But while through the process of researching I find there are few papers published under similar topics. Or to say with the same research work as what is in Y. And I am a independent researcher just listing/downloading papers related to X. 
So is there a website on which I can just upload these plagiarised articles/papers and flag it? We do have plagiarism checkers but all I want to know is if there exists one such tool where anyone from anywhere can upload a plagiarised paper.

Comment: I don't understand. "Similar topics" doesn't imply plagiarism, nor does "same research work". Also, charging plagiarism is a pretty serious action.

Comment: How do you know those other papers are plagiarized? Just because they are on the same topic does not imply or guarantee plagiarism....

Comment: I suggest that readers take this question at face value, and assume that OP actually means _plagiarism_ —for example, one paper copying large swathes of text verbatim from another, perhaps with minor cosmetic changes—and not merely parallel discovery.

Answer (score 4):

I would worry that a web site that lets anyone charge plagiarism of specific work would be in for a lot of lawsuits unless there was a mechanism for actually verifying the charge.

Charging plagiarism is a very serious action. You'd better be sure before you make a public charge. It could be interpreted in some places as libel, a form of [defamation](https://defamation.laws.com/defamation-laws/libel-vs-slander). At a minimum it would cause an uproar.

I don't think many organizations would be brave/foolish enough to host such a site.

If you think something is plagiarized, then work through existing academic structures to correct it. Also, be aware that you might be entirely wrong. Parallel (independent) work, especially in popular research areas, is very common.

Comment: I agree in general, and especially for something as reasonable as being on "similar topics"... However, a minor point: It'd be more likely to be interpreted as libel in this (website) case, rather than slander.

Comment: @Anyon, technically correct. I'll edit. https://defamation.laws.com/defamation-laws/libel-vs-slander. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer. "work through existing academic structures to correct it" means contacting the editors of the journals who published the paper, and suggesting they take a look.